# Find one positive integer sequence $a_{n}$ such $\frac{a^2_{i-1}+a^2_{i}}{2}$ are square number

Tags: number-theory

Find  a postive integer sequence $\{a_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ such

(1)$$0<a_{1}<a_{2}<a_{3}<\cdots<a_{n}$$
(2):$$\dfrac{a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}}{2},\dfrac{a^2_{2}+a^2_{3}}{2},\dfrac{a^2_{3}+a^2_{4}}{2},\cdots,\dfrac{a^2_{n-1}+a^2_{n}}{2}$$are all square numbers

@achille find $a_{n}=7^{n-1}$ such  this two condition.Now I consider this following

**Add question**
Let $n\geq 2$ be a positive integer. Find the minimum value of positive integer $m$ for which there exist positive integers 
 $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ such

(1)$$0<a_{1}<a_{2}<a_{3}<\cdots<a_{n}=m$$
(2):$$\dfrac{a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}}{2},\dfrac{a^2_{2}+a^2_{3}}{2},\dfrac{a^2_{3}+a^2_{4}}{2},\cdots,\dfrac{a^2_{n-1}+a^2_{n}}{2}$$are all square numbers

Comment: What on earth are $a_{i}$ and $a_{i-1}$ in the title???

Comment: $1,7,7^2,7^3,\ldots$

Comment: @achillehui,Nice.How  find minumum of the $a_{n}$

Comment: @communnites That sounds difficult, but I think the greedy method gives this sequence as an upper bound: https://oeis.org/A056220.  It's rather slow-growing so maybe there is a way to prove it's optimal.

Comment: @ErickWong,Thanks,I can't open your links,It is said $m_{min}=2n^2-1$

Comment: @communnites "Average of the squares of two consecutive terms is also a square. In fact: (2*n^2 - 1)^2 + (2*(n+1)^2 - 1)^2 = 2*(2*n^2 + 2*n + 1)^2. - Matias Saucedo (solomatias(AT)yahoo.com.ar), Aug 18 2008"

Answer (score 1):

this sequence is pretty good
$$ 2 n^2 + 4 n + 1 $$
I see, i was starting this with $n=0,$ and 
$$ 2 n^2 + 4 n + 1 = 2 (n+1)^2 - 1. $$
So, this is actually the same as the quote by Andras Salamon if we shift to beginning with $n=1,$
$$ 2 n^2 - 1. $$

```
    1    7    5
    7   17   13
   17   31   25
   31   49   41
   49   71   61
   71   97   85
   97  127  113
  127  161  145
  161  199  181
  199  241  221
  241  287  265
```